# Kubernetes pod exec using python client not very interactive

Tags: python, kubernetes, containers, exec, kubernetes-pod

I am following the official [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/pod_exec.py) to exec into a Kubernetes container using the python kubernetes-client library.

```
from kubernetes import config
from kubernetes.client.api import core_v1_api
from kubernetes.stream import stream


def exec_commands(api_instance):

    resp = stream(api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
                  'busybox',
                  'default',
                  command=['/bin/sh'],
                  stderr=True, stdin=True,
                  stdout=True, tty=True,
                  _preload_content=False)

    while resp.is_open():
        resp.update(timeout=1)
        if resp.peek_stdout():
            print("%s" % resp.read_stdout())
        if resp.peek_stderr():
            print("%s" % resp.read_stderr())

        command = input()

        if command == "exit":
            break
        else:
            resp.write_stdin(command + "\n")

    resp.close()


def main():
    config.load_kube_config("~/.kube/config")
    core_v1 = core_v1_api.CoreV1Api()
    exec_commands(core_v1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above code is able to exec into the container. However, the shell is not very interactive. The issues with it are:-

1. Arrow keys do not work. When pressing arrows, exec shows `^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[B` characters
2. Tab auto-complete does not work. When I press tab character, it takes tab as input white spaces instead of auto-completing.
3. I have to hit the enter key twice to get the command output. Example:-

   ```
   ls


   / # ls
   abc.txt       etc           root          tmp
   bin           home          sys           usr
   dev           proc          terminfo.src  var
   / #
   ```
4. Cannot work with vi editor inside the container because of not been able to use arrow and escape key. Example:-

```
first line
^[[C^[[D^[[C^[[B
```

Is there any better way to exec into a kubernetes container programmatically using python?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to add comment so will reply here.

I suggest looking into [readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) or [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) for properly handling arrow keys and other terminal related issues.

```
first line
^[[C^[[D^[[C^[[B
```

You are seeing this because the terminal uses escape sequences to properly handle the arrow keys. `print("%s" % resp.read_stdout())` this combo most probably does not handle that well, that's why you see part of the escape sequence and some other letters.

Might I suggest looking into [pipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). That way you will not be passing your input/output through `print` and `read_stdout` functions, which are more suitable for strings and not terminals.

Comment: By just adding `import readline`, the arrow keys navigation work perfectly fine. However, the experience of using vi editor in the exec container is still very pathetic. Is there any way to improve the experience of using vi editor inside the exec container?

Comment: Also adding `readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')` code provides tab-complete. But it auto-completes files in my local directories instead of container directories. Example `abc.txt` file is in container. When I press tab, it auto completes to `exec.py` which is my python file in current directory.

Comment: Vi editor issue is most likely due to terminal emulation (rather something missing from it), so I suggest taking a look at ncurses linked in the post.

Comment: After reading the curses package, it seems it creates windows and other stuff on top of the current terminal and not on the remote exec terminal. Could you please give pointers on changing the default terminal behavior similar to [this](https://miminar.fedorapeople.org/_preview/openshift-enterprise/registry-redeploy/go_client/executing_remote_processes.html) in Golang?